# На этой оптимисти...ой ноте

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

> На этой оптимистической ноте...

или

> На этой оптимистичной ноте...

Пишут и так, и так. А как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) *На этой **оптимистической ноте** мы и закончили разговор* (22 примера в Нацкорпусе).

(2) *На этой **оптимистичной** ноте предлагаю закончить* (4 примера в Нацкорпусе).

Хотя в словаре прилагательные считаются синонимами, все-таки относительный суффикс СК ближе к значению "проникнутый оптимизмом", а суффикс Н чаще выражает внутреннее качество предмета.

Поэтому вариант (1) кажется более предпочтительным.

Comment: Sharon, ответите на мой вопрос? Спасибо!